# How standalone installation of vim plugin can be done in Unix

Tags: vim

At my work I want to use vim plugins but I cannot install plugins via git hub command which are mentioned in forums. I need to install plugins manually by copying required files but it does not work. Can someone let me know how to install vim plugins manually in Linux environment .

Here are the steps i have done:

1. Downloaded github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim
2. Created ~/.vim/bundle, ~/.vim/plugin directories
3. Copied vundle.vim into ~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim

I have copied below message in .vimrc file

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim 
call vundle#begin() 
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' 
Plugin 'file:/nfs/iind/home/bvedula/.vim/plugin' 
call vundle#end() " required 
filetype plugin indent on " required
```

When i run vim in my xterm i get following error:

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vimrc, 
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin, 
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim', 
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'file:~/.vim/plugin
```

Comment: Please post here commands you've tried and error messages if any.

Comment: Here are the steps i have done. 1. Downloaded https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim 2. Created ~/.vim/bundle, ~/.vim/plugin directories 3. Copied vundle.vim into ~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim 4. I have copied below message in .vimrc file

Comment: set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'file:/nfs/iind/home/bvedula/.vim/plugin'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required  When i run vim in my xterm i get following error : Error detected while processing ~/.vimrc, E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin, E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim', E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'file:~/.vim/plugin

Comment: Why can't you use "git hub commands"? If you don't have git on that machine vundle will not work.

Comment: I cannot access external git hub source from my work station . It is blocked. Does vundle  wont work standalone ?

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that `vundle#begin` is unknown, means that Vundle.vim was not even loaded. Looks like you have `vundle.vim` instead of `Vundle.vim` (with uppercase first letter) in the `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim`.

But anyway Vundle is not a good choice if you don't have access to the Internet.

Instead you can use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) which doesn't try to download plugins and only loads them:

> any plugins you wish to install can be extracted to a subdirectory
>   under ~/.vim/bundle, and they will be added to the 'runtimepath'